# Is questioner or answerer advised about comment after latter has been deleted?

Tags: support, comment, deletion, notifications

If I make a comment, the recipient will be advised.
 But if he has not read it and I delete it, will he still be advised and able to read it *after* my deletion?

Comment: I believe for a limited the comment-notification persists after deletion and the user could read it in the inbox. They will not see it on the site though.

Comment: Some related posts on meta.SE: [If I leave a comment, then delete it, does a person still get notified?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19092/if-i-leave-a-comment-then-delete-it-does-a-person-still-get-notified) and [If a comment triggers a notification, what happens to the notification if the comment is deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129973/if-a-comment-triggers-a-notification-what-happens-to-the-notification-if-the-co). They are quite old though, so I am not sure to which extent they are still reliable.

Comment: And an older post on this site: [If I make an @user comment, then delete it, does the user still get notified?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7145/if-i-make-an-user-comment-then-delete-it-does-the-user-still-get-notified)

Answer (score 1):

Georges, this just happened. I left a comment at a question; the OP edited the question and left me a comment to take a look. Maybe 15 minutes later he deleted the entire post. However, I was notified of the comment.

From your wording, you are asking about when someone deletes a specific comment, not an entire post. Oh, well. In this case, everything will still be in place for viewing. Note that, in [The Intern with Robert de Niro](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2361509/), a turning point occurs when they go to the home of Anne Hathaway's mother to delete an email/text/whatever mistakenly sent to the mother's computer.

See [Exhibit 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848030/equivalent-notation-for-second-partial-derivative-of-a-quadratic-form?noredirect=1#comment3781123_1848030) or [Exhibit 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848030/equivalent-notation-for-second-partial-derivative-of-a-quadratic-form).